# Google PlayStore warning : once the update is complete, they will no longer install APK targeting 22 version of the SDK or earlier

Tags: android, google-play, warnings

Received below warning from PlayStore, What does it means?

```
 Users with version 15 of the APK (targeting 22 version of the SDK or earlier) will perform the update. However, once the update is complete, they will no longer install APK targeting 22 version of the SDK or earlier.

Trick

If this change is desired, make sure that users doing in the future to update this APK to spend 23 or later.
```

Old Version details :

```
 android:minSdkVersion="18"
 android:targetSdkVersion="19"
 android:compileSdkVersion="21"
```

Latest version details :

```
 android:minSdkVersion="18"
 android:targetSdkVersion="25"
 android:compileSdkVersion="25"
```

Comment: Where you are getting this warning? On playstore while releasing the app ?

Comment: yes Hardik, at release build

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Targeting API 23 or later means you must [request dangerous permissions at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). The warning is staying that this is a one way switch: there is no way to revert back to targeting API 22 or earlier once you make the switch to the runtime permission model. The Dev Console is just confirming that you do indeed want to make the permanent switch.